# iOS 8 didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge not getting called for WKWebView Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl-certificate, wkwebview

I am new to iOS development.  I have a project where I have to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView.  Its a simple webpage with javascript to Objective-C and other way round integration.  It is working fine except when I try to open a server with self-signed certificate.  On Safari it shows a dialog box where we can choose to continue.  However on my Application I cannot bypass this.

For some reason I have to run it with self-signed certificate.

The Delegate method didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge is never called.  Other delegate methods are working fine.  I know didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge is depreciated in iOS8 but can someone please tell me the workaround for this.  As I am a newbie so a complete working delegate method and/or any other changes in the code will be highly appreciated.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mywebsite.com/Default.aspx"];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

[[self webView] loadRequest:request];

}

// And the delegate method that is not getting called is 
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler {
    SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    CFDataRef exceptions = SecTrustCopyExceptions(serverTrust);
    SecTrustSetExceptions(serverTrust, exceptions);
    CFRelease(exceptions);

completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,
                  [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust]);
```

}

Comment: did you find any solution for didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge? In my case also it never gets called. Also as its in deprecated in iOS8, how can we achieve this in iOS8?

Comment: I couldn't find any solution so I changed certificate on server with a valid one to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1):

This has been confirmed as a bug by Apple. It has been fixed in iOS9.

Comment: Can you please add references confirming the fix?

Comment: @Phani I filed a bug to Apple, which is fixed now. Unfortunately, Apple's bug reports cannot be seen by other users. I have verified the fix in my project, it works correctly in iOS 9.0 (XCode 7.0). I'm sorry I cannot share my project here, but this scenario is really easy to test with a simple WKWebView and the code from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet you posted, i didn't see you were setting the class as the navigationDelegate of the webview..

Your view controller should implement the protocol `WKNavigationDelegate` and you need to add the below snippet for the delegate to be invoked..

```
[self webView].navigationDelegate = self;
```